# Client A =》proxy server B=》target server C. How does client A process the addresses of B and C

Tags: python, node.js, http, proxy

Is the destination to which the request is sent determined by the address in the request line? I think that's the right idea.Based on this, my guess is that A puts B's address in the request line and C's address in the request header or body.  As a result, there are some problems in the actual code. Because I don't have enough reputation, I can only use links. A's request is written in Python, and the proxy server code is written in NodeJS.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHCdi.png

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're actually asking.  If client A wants to make a request to `http://juejin.cn`, it looks that domain up the DNS and sends the request to the IP address that DNS gives it.  If there is a proxy in use on the server-end of things, then that IP address will be the IP address of the proxy, not of the actual target server (that's how the server configures things to go through the proxy).  If the proxy is on the client, then it will transparently be installed on the local gateway forcing all outbound connections through that gateway to go through the proxy.

Comment: Once a server-side proxy receives the request, it does whatever it wants to with the request and then, if it decides to pass it onto actual server host, then it adds a few proxy-specific headers to the request and makes a new request to the actual server host.  When the response comes back to the proxy, it then pipes that response back to the original client.